# Why is my Docker container not running my Nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, containers, dockerfile

**End goal**: To spin up a docker container running my expressjs application on port 3000 (as if I am using npm start).

**Details**:
I am using Windows 10 Enterprise:

[image: System Specs]

This a very basic, front-end `Expressjs` application.
It runs fine using `npm start` – no errors.

Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM node:8.11.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY src .

CMD node src/index.js

EXPOSE 3000
```

**Steps**:
I am able to create an image, using basic docker build command:

```
docker build –t portfolio-img .
```

Running the image (I am using this command from a tutorial [www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/deploying-first-container](http://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/deploying-first-container)):

```
docker run -d --name portfolio-container -p 3000:3000 portfolio-img
```

The container is not running. It is created, since I can inspect it, but it has exited after the command. I am guessing I did something wrong with the last command, or I am not giving the correct instructions in the dockerfile.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Already have searched a lot on the docker documentation and on here.

Comment: `docker logs portfolio-container` output?

Comment: It's also useful to try running it like `$ docker run -it portfolio-container bash` which will let you inspect things inside and see if perhaps your files aren't where you think they are, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I finally got it to work.
For some reason one of my folders (public) did not appear to be copied properly into the workdir. I am saying this because it did not locate the "index.html" file. I am assuming because the directory was incorrectly specified. So what I ended up doing was just to copy my entire work directory, and use .dockerignore and exclude the node_modules.
Finally, I have used a different command:
docker run -it -d -p 3000:3000 portfolio-image